# web2py: actions after submitting form

Tags: web2py

I want to execute some code only after the user submit a form and the form is accepted. I tried the following codes, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
def new():
    mform=SQLFORM(db.url_tag)
    if mform.process().accepted:
        response.flash = 'form accepted'
    else:
        response.flash =  'e'
        print mform.vars.id
    return locals() #I have other variables in the function
```

In my html, I basically used

```
{{=mform.custom.widget.XX}}
{{=mform.custom.submit}}
```

Another question is, after user submit the form, how could I get the latest submitted record? In my case, will mform.vars.id be the latest record id?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please show all of your code (there are more pieces that you could have missed). Also, please elaborate on "doesn't seem to work". What happens, and what are you expecting?

Comment: I realized it's because I linked the wrong form. mform=SQLFORM(db.url_tag) Just a silly mistake.